# How to restrict to generic types to be the same subtype of another generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to declare a type that represents a changing of some object.

For example:

```ts
const test: SomeType = {
    a: 1,
    b: "foo"
};

const changing1: Changing<SomeType> = {
    obj: test,
    was: {
        a: test.a
    },
    now: {
        a: 3
    }   // Correct one

const changing2: Changing<SomeType> = {
    obj: test,
    was: {
        a: test.a
    },
    now: {
        b: "bar"
    }   // Incorrect one
```

I've been already trying to do like this:

```ts
type Changing<T, K = {[R in keyof T]: T[R]}, P extends K = {[R in keyof K]: K[R]}> = {
    obj: T,
    was: K,
    now: P
}
```

The idea was to restrict P as an extension of K but with the same members. It appears not to work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a mapped type to build up all the possible options for each property and then extract all options into a union. This will make the case you expect to be an error an error:

```
interface SomeType {
    a: number,
    b: string
}
const test: SomeType = {
    a: 1,
    b: "foo"
};

const changing1: Changing<SomeType> = {
    obj: test,
    was: {
        a: test.a
    },
    now: {
        a: 3
    } 
}

const changing2: Changing<SomeType> = { // error
    obj: test,
    was: {
        a: test.a
    },
    now: {
        b: "bar"
    }  
}

type Changing<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: {
        obj: T,
        was: Pick<T, P>
        now: Pick<T, P>
    }
}[keyof T]
```

Comment: It actially works! Thanks!
But can I somehow make these two Picks to be the same subset of T?
The way you did this forbids only cases without intersection of these two Picks. ({a,b} and {b, c} would work, but must not)

Comment: @НикитаЮдин You want to allow any combination of keys, as long as it's the same keys ? It can be done but not without an extra function. The above approach of generating the union will not work as generating all possible combinations while possible (and hackish) is prohibitively expensive for the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!